# Term Filter with "now" in elasticsearch 1.7.1

Tags: elasticsearch

When using a Term Filter, I'm not able to use `now` elasticsearch 1.7.1 anymore. It worked fine in previous versions, but now it returns:

```
nested: IllegalArgumentException[Invalid format: \"now/y\"]
```

A query example is:

```
GET _search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "price": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "prices"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "valid": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "prices.referred_year": "now/y"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "ranged": {
              "range": {
                "field": "prices.price",
                "ranges": [
                  {
                    "to": 10
                  },
                  {
                    "from": 10
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Schema:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/' -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "product": {
      "properties": {
        "prices": {
          "type": "nested",
          "include_in_parent": true,
          "properties": {
            "price": {
              "type": "float"
            },
            "referred_year": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "year"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Document example:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/product/1' -d '{
  "prices": [
    {
      "referred_year": "2015",
      "price": "10.00"
    },
    {
      "referred_year": "2016",
      "price": "11.00"
    }
  ]
}'
```

Expected result for the aggregation (gotten by substituting `now/y` with `2015`):

```
"aggregations": {
  "price": {
    "doc_count": 2,
    "valid": {
      "doc_count": 1,
      "ranged": {
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "*-10.0",
            "to": 10,
            "to_as_string": "10.0",
            "doc_count": 0
          },
          {
            "key": "10.0-*",
            "from": 10,
            "from_as_string": "10.0",
            "doc_count": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`now/y` etc still works fine in the Range Filter and in queries.

I appreciate any help on this. Thanks!

------- UPDATE -------

So, it seems `now` doesn't work in Term Filters at all, no matter the rounding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, although I haven't found any documentation saying so, it seems using the `now` operator is not allowed in Term Filters. Which actually makes sense.

The correct query would be:

```
GET test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "price": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "prices"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "valid": {
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "prices.referred_year": {
                "gte": "now/y",
                "lte": "now/y"
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "ranged": {
              "range": {
                "field": "prices.price",
                "ranges": [
                  {
                    "to": 10
                  },
                  {
                    "from": 10
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```